# Using distinct keyword returns invalid rows in linked server

Tags: sql-server-2012, distinct, linked-server

I am getting some strange results from a query in SQL server that I can't work out.
The query is

```
  select
    ref5
  from
    t_wholesale_history
  left outer join
    AP21..AP21.REFTBL on
    reftbl.tblname = 'SOrder'
    and reftbl.rg_ord = 5
  left outer join
    AP21..AP21.REFCODE on
    refcode.code = t_wholesale_history.ref5
    and refcode.rgidx = reftbl.rgidx
    and refcode.active = 1
  where
    t_wholesale_history.ref5 is not null
    and refcode.rcidx is null
```

which looks in a remote database and lists all records where REF5 doesn't exist. The above query returns 0 rows (which is correct).
Now, if I change the `select ref5` to a `select distinct ref5`, I get 5 rows!
Why does using the word distinct returns rows? The rows it returns are not even the correct rows so this doesn't make sense to me.

Unfortunately I can't provide a fiddle of this due to the remote server complication, but I am guessing the fact I am getting these results has something to do with the remote server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not that this helps you, but I'm curious.  What happens if you use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Good question. It returns the same result as using distinct.